# Change the children of a component dynamically in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it a way to change the children of a component dynamically? I have a component which wraps other components, recursively walks the children, what I want is to change the text of the childrens that are string. e.g.

```
render() {
   const func = (node) => {
    React.Children.forEach(node.children, (childNode) => {
      if (childNode && childNode.props && typeof childNode.props.children === "object") {
        func(childNode.props);
      }
      else if (typeof childNode.props.children === "string"){
        console.log(childNode.props);
      }
    })
  }

  func(this.props);

  return <span>{ this.props.children }</span>;
}
```

Setting childNode.props.children === "something" inside the else is failing, children is read-only.
Any idea how I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

React props are read only indeed as it stated in React docs. You can follow JSX approach, which always creates new element, instead of changing existing element props. At later stage element is reconciled with existing React component in the Virtual DOM.

To change props of the element via JavaScript you can clone element using [React.cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) method. Please note, you should not render this.props.children in this case, instead render new resulting element tree:

```
render() {
   const func = (children) => {
    return React.Children.map(children, (childNode) => {
      if (typeof childNode === "string")
        return "something"; // cover case: <div>text<div></div></div>
      if (typeof childNode.props.children === "string")
        return React.cloneElement(childNode, [], "something");
      return React.cloneElement(childNode, [], func(childNode.props.children));
    })
  }

  return <span>{ func(this.props.children) }</span>;
}
```

Comment: Strange I tried [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgRBWd?editors=0010) but   nothing came out.

Comment: If you have trouble opening codepen try from incognito browser mode.

Comment: Right, return was missing on 3rd line (function should return result of a map). See updated and refined [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPWyqQ) . Notice that it does not render subcomponents while crawling children, e.g. it won't iterate through their rendered children, rendering happens at later stage after VDOM reconciliation.

Comment: Thanks for the additional effort.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest having dynamic children list in state of the component and render them.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MichalCafe/okavmzdt/)**

```
class Hello extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      children: [
        <div>test</div>,
        <div>test2</div>
      ]
    };

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
        children: [
          <div>new!</div>,
          <div>changed!</div>
        ]
      });
    }, 2000);

  }

  render() {
    return <p>{this.state.children}</p>;
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

You can apply this concept in your app.

Comment: Well, the component should be able to used anywhere, and wrap other components (`this.props.children`), which can be deeply nested, and not maintain state. What you did is just a normal component with flat hierarchy, I dont really see its value.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is broken:  "<a class='gotoLine' href='#55:9'>55:9</a> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&lt;'        Under Chrome on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to iterate over the `this.props.children` and to create the custom children like this.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.state = { no: 'need' };
  }
  
render() {
  
    let children = []; // children 
    let k = 0; // key
    this.props.children.forEach( function(child) {       
      if( "string" === typeof child.props.children ){      
        console.log(child);
        let enew = React.cloneElement( child,  child.props, "new_" + k );
        k++;        
        children.push(enew);  
      }else{
        children.push(child);  
      }
    });  
 

  return <span>{ children }</span>;
 }
}



var NewComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
       <div className="awesome" style={{border: '1px solid red'}}>
        Hello World!  
      </div>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent>
    <NewComponent />
    <div>Hello</div>    
    <div>World</div>
  </Parent>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Based on your need you may even create new element instead of cloning the existing one.

```
let enew = React.createElement( 'div',  {key: k, className: 'new'}, "new" );
```

Comment: React guys [provided React.Children utilities for dealing with props.children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children). Since this.props.children is not always array iteration will fail, for instance:<Parent>text</Parent>